# Updating Values in Workflow Rule

Tags: workflow, picklist

I have two Picklist Values field in account object

1. `picklist field called type__c` Values: Rose, jasmine, sunflower
2. `color__c` Values: Pink, white, yellow

When I am creating or updating the record in account object,if I choose the type, color value should automatically update in `color__c` field

eg.:- Rose - pink, jasmine - white, sunflower - yellow

Is it possible using workflow rule? How can we achieve this in a single workflow rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that using field dependencies
Please refer following link for more detials.
 field dependencies will be more effecient as in future if your pick-list values gets added then simply you can handle dependencies by doing minimum configuration change.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_simple_app_adv_field_dependencies_try_it_out.htm

More point about dependent fields
– The value selected in the controlling field affects the values available in the dependent field.
– A dependent field works in conjunction with a controlling field to filter its values.
–  We can define custom picklist fields as controlling or dependent fields.
– Standard picklist filed must be controlling fields. We cannot define standard picklist fields as dependent fields.
– We can define default values for controlling field. But we cannot define default fields for dependent fields.
– We cannot define multi-select picklist as controlling.
– We can define checkbox as controlling field only.

Ref: http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/field-dependency-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using single workflow and without using field dependency as mentioned by you,

1. Create a formula field - Type_Color__c

   `Case(ISPICKVAL(Type__c),'Rose','Pink','Jasmine','White','Sunflower','Yellow')`
2. Create a work flow rule and add a field update for Color__c and add formula as below in formula editor

   `Type__Color__c`

Note - This solution will work only if Color__c is a text field and not a picklist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53929/discussion-between-snehakem-and-learning-user).